# Changing html based on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an invasion-power forum, and I'm trying to use javascript to change specific accounts profiles, but I can't seem to change the background. Right now on the background picker it shows this

```
<span id='customprofile' data-backgroundClass='ipsfocus_bg1' style='background-color: {theme="ifBg1_hex"}; {{if theme.ifBg1_image}}background-image: url({theme="ifBg1_image"});{{endif}} background-position: {theme="ifBg1_position"}; background-size: {theme="ifBg1_size"}'></span>
```

for one of the background options, but what I want to be able to do is have a script that if, say the url includes "1" than a different span is shown rather than this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have 2 spans in the page

```
<span id="special" style="display:none;">Special</span>
<span id="normal"  style="display:none;">Normal</span>
<script>
  var el;

  // check if current page contains a 1
  if (location.href.indexOf("1") !== -1) {
     // select special SPAN
     el = document.getElementById("special");
  } else {
     // otherwiose select normal SPAN
     el = document.getElementById("normal");
  }

  // make it visible
  el.style.display = 'inline';
</script>
```

Comment: It is still displaying the spans with the normal id, and I added a console log to check if it is getting 1, and it is, but still displaying ids with normal